# angles commands in superclass

Tags: python

how do you write a command that turn left or right at an angle in a superclass is it like this:

```
def left(self):
  self.position += self.angle
  return (self.position)
```

is it the same as the forward and back command

Comment: The question is fairly vague. Please elaborate.

Comment: you'll need to provide a bit of background; the question doesn't make very much sense on its own

Comment: Still not read the tutorial? Well ...

Comment: What does a superclass have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are interested by something like the logo turtle. Look at http://docs.python.org/library/turtle.html

If so, the left function doesn't change the position of the turtle but its orientation.

```
def left(self, angle):
    self.angle -= angle*2*math.pi/360
```

Comment: its part of Object oriented Python